# Prevent the number of characters over 20 to pass the validation

Tags: php, regex

I have this light regular expression to validate the coordinates: `^([0-9.,-]+){18,20}$^`. If the coordinates for example is 33.431441,-170.15625 and are under 18 characters, I'll get an error message. Good! But if I add more characters to say 23 or more it will pass even if I have set an lock to 20.

You can test the regexp on http://regexpal.com/.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets `strlen()` will only check for length, a requirement here is that only numbers, period, comma, and dash be allowed.

Comment: so first do the regexp, then do the strlen check, if passes both then continue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the leading carat, or you are only checking the last 18-20 characters in the string:

```
/^[0-9\.,-]{18,20}$/
```

Edit: also, drop the plus sign, as others have noted.
Edit2: Parens are superfluous
Edit3: need to escape the period (otherwise, it matches any character)

Comment: Many thanks! My problem is now solved and I will accept your answer as soon as I can :)

Comment: thanks, but in my haste I left another mistake in, please see edit 3

Answer (score 2):

It should be just `^([0-9.,-]){18,20}$`. The `+` means one or more of the preceding elements, and then you have 18 to 20 of *those*. You want just 18 to 20 of the preceding elements. You don't need the caret at the end as that means "beginning of string"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion if you want to constrain the limits and validate the coordinate format.

Assuming Lat,Long:

```
^-?\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,5})?,-?\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,5})?$
```

The comma will always consume 1 characters.
Max longitude primary digits are 3 characters.
Max latitude primary digits are 2 characters.
Optional decimal points take up 2 characters.
Optional polarity is 2 characters.

This leaves us with 10 characters reserved, giving us 5 left over on each side for decimal places.  You can adjust \d{1,5} to something like \d{4,5} and enforce the decimal places if you require a minimum of 18.

Comment: Thanks but according to Regex Tester (http://regexpal.com/) your validation will only validate `12,13.48219` from `59.329512,13.482199`.

Comment: Thats because you probably trimmed off the ^ and $ characters.  They indicate the start and end of the evaluation.  Without the '^' character, you're only going going to get '12' out of '59.329512'.

Comment: Ah. Okej. But I tested it on my website before I tested it on Regex Tester and I got an error when the coordinates was right. Therefore I tested it on Regex Tester too see what was wrong with it, so to speak.